# Unit testing of custom WCF extensions like custom behaviors and inspectors

Tags: .net, wcf, unit-testing, mstest

For some need, I have written implementations of `IServiceBehavior`, `IEndpointBehavior`, `IDispatchMessageInspector` and all my WCF services use them.

Do I need to unit test them? If yes, how do I unit test these custom WCF extension points ? I am using MSTest.

Answer (score -1):

You should have two sets of tests:

1. Unit tests for your custom implementations of those interfaces
2. Integration tests for your services (that will also cover interfaces, but in *full, real-usage setup* scenario)

Unit testing implementation should be done just as unit testing anything else. This really narrows down to verifying what those custom implementations do. Plain, old unit tests.

However, note that there are two major obstacles to successfully unit test such WCF bits implementations:

- WCF context headers (or simply put context alone) will be difficult to work with in terms of mocking, as they come from static class ([OperationContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.current.aspx))
- Mocking some of the method parameters might be impossible as they are sealed (for example [InstanceContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontext.aspx)) or fairly complex

Naturally, all this can be overcame with usage of proper techniques and tools:

- For sealed classes that mocking won't work, you simply create instances (with help of tools like **[AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/)**) and set up objects/dependencies graphs manually (might be time consuming, but in most cases you don't use all of them).
- Whatever can be mocked/stubbed should be done so, **[FakeItEasy](http://code.google.com/p/fakeiteasy)** let's you simply stub any class as long as it's not sealed (doesn't have to be an interface). It's great to deal with unused method parameters.
- To deal with `OperationContext.Current` (and similar), you'll probably need to alter your design a bit. Precisely, all the classes using current context in some ways will need to implement `protected virtual` method exposing it (or any other part that might be useful, say request headers):

  ```
  protected virtual MessageHeaders GetContextHeaders()
  {
      return OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers;
  }
  ```

  Then you'll need to create derived, *testable* class that will instead return mocked/stubbed version of those headers (or context or whatever you plan to use) and create instances of that class in unit tests.

Once you're done with unit testing, [integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) should be a brief walk. Simply set your objects as they would be used in real-world scenario... and verify that they work as expected.

---

**Side note**: unit testing can also be done in an easier way, however you'll either need paid tools (like [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/typemock-isolator-product3), which let's you mock static/sealed classes) and/or bit heavier/complex ones ([PEX/Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/)).